# Scheme eval simple circumvention

Tags: list, scheme, eval

I am currently learning scheme as part of a course I am taking. The way it has been taught to me is with generous use of the eval expression, and most of the provided examples I am testing do not work as described. The more I read, it becomes obvious that I should not be using eval so freely. I have seen some circumvention methods in javaScript but I am looking for something specific to Scheme.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044499/eval-in-scheme) provides some info about when eval may necessary. That doesn't really help me figure out a good circumvention method.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595360/seeking-clarification-on-scheme-eval) has more good info but doesn't give any way to avoid eval in my situation.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415909/why-does-this-not-evaluate-in-scheme) came closest to answering my question, and helped me to understand why eval does not necessarily work as expected, but I am still unclear on what a good replacement for the eval expression would be.

What I am looking for is **the standard** way to do this :

```
(define (add a_list)
    (cond
        ((null? a_list) 0)
        (eval(cons '+ a_list)))
)

(add '(3 4 8 12 30))
```

without eval so that it returns **57**. Currently it returns **(+ 3 4 8 12 30)**.
[This link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/03wi/scheme/basics.html) seems to suggest that, say, (+ 3 4) would automatically evaluate to 7, but I am getting just the list printed back to me as an expression with no evaluation.

It will work fine written the following ways:

```
(define (add a_list)
    (cond
        ((null? a_list) 0)
        (eval(eval(cons '+ a_list))))
)

(add '(3 4 8 12 30))
```

returns **57** but one of the **evals** seems to do nothing. And :

```
(define (add a_list)
  (eval(cons '+ a_list))
)

(add '(3 4 8 12 30))
```

returns **57** but does not check for an empty list.

Any help removing it altogether (or only using it if absolutely necessary) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples mentioned, you don't need `eval`, a simple `apply` will work. And your suspicions are correct, we should avoid using `eval` most of the time - it's considered "evil".

```
(define (add a_list)
  (apply + a_list))
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I didn't know apply existed... I think my prof's info is out of date by several years.